# Issue with href two separate page with slide animation in mobile jquery

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

i have two separate pages, `index.html` and `profile.html`, and i want to href index.html to profile.html with slide animation so i tried,

```
   $.mobile.changePage("/profile.html" , { 
     transition: "slideUp", 
     reloadPage: true });
```

in index.html. i guess this code does not execute or say update head of profile.html and some how reloadPage not working, it is just targeting body tag. is something wrong or how can i reload whole profile page with slide animation?

Comment: it should work normally and fully load profile.html not only fetching page div.

Answer (score 1):

you are not loading a page "with slide animation". The slide animation is a CSS effect you can add to any div element you want by adding the class(es) JQM is using (try `slide in`).

So when JQM is loading a page it fetches the content of the first `<div data-role="page">` it finds on the page and "throws away" everything else.

The new `"page"` is then positioned using CSS depending on the transition you set, so normally `pos:absolute; top:0; right: screen-width`. Then the classes are added and the page slides in.

Since JQM does not parse anything outside of the page, your `profile <head>` is disregarded. To fix, all scripts should be available on all pages, because you never know where the user starts and you need to make sure everything you need is on board.

Comment: So should i fire initialisation script of different pages after completion of animation ? because my all pages need particular initialization

Comment: Just do it on `pagebeforeshow`. This way whatever you are setting up does not happen in front of the user. Info pagebeforeshow [here](http://api.jquerymobile.com/category/events/)